# Issues with aspnet_compiler and first time load

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

I have a fairly large site trying to solve for first time hit penalties. Attempting to use **aspnet_compiler** to pre-compile does not seem to be working as I thought it would.

I run the command as follows:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
aspnet_compiler -p "C:\Development\Source\WEB" -v / "C:\Staging" -c
```

Web.Config setting as follows (not sure if this matters?)

```
<compilation debug="false" strict="false" batch="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" optimizeCompilations="true">
```

IIS app pool (values can't be changed due to third party references)

- .NET Framework Version: v4.0
- Enable 32-bit Applications: False
- Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic

Running Windows Server 2008R2

When I navigate to the first page (login) in the site (C:\Staging) I get appx. 60 second warm-up in which I can see the files caching/compiling in the temp directory **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files**

My assumption was that by using the aspnet_compiler I would be able to bypass the need for this warm-up cycle. Is there something obvious I'm missing or some other means of pre-compiling such that we don't have this first time penalty?

This seems to happen (no real proof) through the day, possible when the app pool recycles? Again, looking for some way to solve.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; I use the aspnet_compiler tool to change our website start time from ~120 seconds to 8 seconds.  It works *really* well for complex websites with a load of aspx/ascx files.

I use a command like:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler -v / -p C:\Projects\branches\demo3\KenticoCMS -fixednames C:\Projects\branches\demo3precomp

This command is used to build a website that is on it's own domain, and resides in the C:\Projects\branches\demo3\KenticoCMS directory.  I'm outputting to the C:\Projects\branches\demo3precomp directory and I deploy the contents of that to the server.